# Where can I find the live Earth-Sun-Mars angle*, assuming that both planets are in coplanar orbits?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, geometry

*The angle between the line from the earth to the sun and the line from the mars to the sun RIGHT NOW.
I only found the right ascention and declination of Mars, which is measured with respect to Earth. However, I am a bit confused about the March equinox, so I am not sure how I can deduce the angle I am looking from from the information I have.

Comment: I think that the angle sun earth mars is easy. Knowing the  present distance earth sun and earth mars, the triangle (and so the other angles) is given.

Comment: You might try; https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi?CGISESSID=a7fc814bbad770e159b942349e702d39#results or search; NASA horizons system

Answer (score 1):

According to *Mathematica*, using Entity["Planet","Earth"]["HelioCoordinates"] and Entity["Planet","Mars"]["HelioCoordinates"], the current Earth-Sun-Mars angle is 4.35 degrees. But this does *not* assume that they are in coplanar orbits; it uses their actual non-coplanar orbits.

If you want to impose coplanarity, you have to explain in more detail how you want to mathematically do that. For example, if you project the heliocentric coordinates onto the ecliptic plane by using only the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, then the angle is 4.30 degrees.