# Where can I find the true anomaly of the planets on Jan 1st 2000?

Tags: orbital-motion, resource-recommendations, astronomy, solar-system, data

I am trying to code a simulation of the solar system. At present, all the orbits seem correct but I'm placing the planets at their respective periapses at the start of the simulation so the relative angle between the planets, I fear, is all wrong.

This is important to me because I intend to simulate the launching of a probe between Earth and Mars Since there's a 26 month cycle where earth and mars go through every angle together, I realised that a phase offset might mean that the passing of earth and mars may happen with the right frequency but at the wrong point in the orbit.

I have been trying to find a table of data that simply contains the planet' true anomaly (or relative phase angle to earth or some other reference. Just something to define the start point of the orbit.) and I can't seem to find one. I have plenty of pages telling me the mean anomaly, and I've seen simulations that tell you when that simulation is accurate to so the data must exist somewhere.

Any help tracking these anomalies down would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov) ?

Comment: Can I get the true anomaly from that? Findjng the output hard to decipher and Id rather not have to work out the angle from a state vector

Comment: I admit there's a bit of a learning curve to Horizons, but IMHO it's worthwhile reading through the tutorial to learn how to use it, and what data is available. You can get the data in various forms. Ecliptic longitude & latitude is probably most suitable for your needs. You can get the classic Keplerian orbital elements of all the planets, if you want, but they *don't* recommend you use that data for doing long-term sims. OTOH, they do provide formulas for approximate planet positions. See https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?planet_pos

Comment: FWIW, I understand you wanting to calculate this stuff yourself. It's an ancient and honourable thing! OTOH, doing your own sim from scratch isn't going to be as accurate as the JPL ephemerides, which integrate the equations of motion of all the major solar system bodies, including the 343 most massive main belt asteroids. But if you do want to run the computations on your own hardware, check out SPICE https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/spiceconcept.html

Comment: *Mathematica* can give you the true anomaly and other planetary coordinates on any date. See [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589325/where-can-i-find-the-live-earth-sun-mars-angle-assuming-that-both-planets-are/589361). You would use the [Date option](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Planet.html) as in the example computing the position of Venus in the morning sky during 2009.

Comment: Thank you very much gsmith